# Make gestureState return values in steps (grid-like behavior)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using `'react-native-draggable'` to create a floorplan builder and I'm in the process of modifying the package to suite our needs as this package does not support grid-stepped behavior.

By default,

```
const {dx, dy} = gestureState;
```

`dx` / `dy` will always have `0` as starting point regardless of any object's position on the screen — It measures the distance your finger has moved on the x and y from the moment you started draggin an object.

To make the object move in steps, I had the idea of trying to reset the `gestureState` to `0` if `dx` or `dy` is above `20px` / below `-20px` to simulate a grid of 20x20 grid slots. But it seems the values returned by gestureState are constant (which makes sense) so once you start moving, it keeps on measuring until you release.

Any idea of how I would go about solving this?

```
  const handleOnDrag = React.useCallback(
    (e, gestureState) => {
      const {dx, dy} = gestureState; // always returns a value from 0
      const {top, right, left, bottom} = startBounds.current;
      const far = 999999999;
     
      const changeX = clamp(
        dx, // New value it will animate object to (!!)
        Number.isFinite(minX) ? minX - left : -far, // checks if any boundaries are set on X
        Number.isFinite(maxX) ? maxX - right : far, // checks if any boundaries are set on X
      );
      const changeY = clamp(
        dy, // New value it will animate object to (!!)
        Number.isFinite(minY) ? minY - top : -far, // checks if any boundaries are set on Y
        Number.isFinite(maxY) ? maxY - bottom : far, // checks if any boundaries are set on Y
      );

        // Animate object
        pan.current.setValue({x: changeX, y: changeY});
      
        onDrag(e, gestureState);
    },
    [maxX, maxY, minX, minY, onDrag],
  );
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `Math.round()` to round to nearest 50 (or any decimal-number depending on grid size)

```
Math.round(dx/50) * 50
```

and

```
Math.round(dx/50) * 50
```